# Can we decide what should be our sitelinks in google?

Tags: google-search-console, google-crawlers

I have a maths related site and google created the sitelinks for my site , 
:) :) google is giving my site some priority

and i'm using the google web master tools

And there is an option to block any unwanted links from that list...

But the sitelinks are not exactly the subcategories of my site.

Can we decide what should be our sitelinks in google?

**Note: I tried to create a new tag as 'google-sitelinks' but without reputation i could not create such one.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From webmaster tools:

> Google generates these links
>   automatically, but you can remove
>   sitelinks you don't want.

You cannot add your own, but you can remove them.

View this [page on webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en) for more info.

Comment: From google support , 'At the moment, sitelinks are completely automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future.' 

It's good that they may incorporate webmaster input in the future. I think that will help to display the proper sitelinks instead of relying on the alogorithm